# Best support for a granite table top?: Flat bar 316L Stainless Steel or equal box section or unequal box section

Tags: materials, design, structural-analysis, strength

Project is outdoor granite topped table.  Table legs are two isosceles trapezoids crossed together at 90 degrees, with the legs having an internal angle of 80 degrees, made from 100 x 100 x 4mm 316L Stainless Steel equal box section. Granite top will weight either approx. 158.95Kgs (350.5 Lbs) @ 20mm thick or 238Kgs (525 Lbs) @ 30mm thick. Clearance from ground to underside of table top = 700mm. I am stuck on the support frame (which will be back 150mm from perimeter of the Granite) to be welded to the legs .  As I **only have 40mm height to play with** (a downstand of granite will cover the support), and given that the legs are 100 x 100mm box section, what 316L would be the most rigid/strong enough to take the weight of the granite and be welded to the legs? All answers gratefully received, but please bear in mind I have no technical knowledge whatsoever, so just a shopping list please! I have to give the fabricators a drawing that makes sense and just knowing what I want in my garden won't help them!  Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Bear in mind, it's not just about taking the weight of the granite - you also need to resist bending loads eg if someone sits on it. Don't want the granite to crack!

Comment: Absolutely! @Jonathan R Swift But where I come from, tables were made for glasses, not children's ***** so I will definitely be policing it! We're only doing this once!

Comment: Sure - should have no problem if it's just glasses. My kitchen island is a 'bridge' shape, and needed to expect fairly heavy impact from kneading dough, smashing out chocolate moulds, etc. No way I would have been happy with a flat bar in that situation - but yours may see a quieter life!

Comment: Hi MrsJLO. This community is here to provide technical advice and education, not professional design services. Out of consideration for your risk, our liability, and the guidelines of this site, I am voting to close the question. However, I think based on what you've written that you are underestimating your technical ability! If you would consider revising (editing) your question to focus on the technical problem, rather than a shopping list, that could be a great fit for this site.

Comment: 316 is an expensive alloy! I would lean toward a box or channel, will give much more strength per volume (aka cost) of material

Answer (score 0):

The cross-section of the  legs will be doing most of the supporting for the granite weigh in this case. Even the maximum of weight 238kg, is not going to be too taxing on the supporting frame. (For example if you had vertical legs a flat bar of almost any thickness more that 3 mm would be OK).

Since you have this small inward angle, there will be some small danger for buckling horizontally.

For simplicity, I would go for a flat bar with width of 100mm and thickness between 10 to 15[mm] (that may also be overengineered) but you will be on the safe side.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it properly - I only want to see the legs, not the support frame, so need 316L that's short in height, but strong enough to take the weight of the granite, that's how I got to thinking whether a flat bar would work. So, a couple of questions: 1. If I have to use box section, then am I correct in thinking that equal box is stronger than unequal box? and 2. If I prefer using flat bar, what thickness should I use? Many thanks.

Comment: in my answered , I focused on the shopping list, and I did not read through your question (because probably soon will be closed).

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for your help and time. Much appreciated.

Comment: Didn't see this comment! "flat bar with width of 100mm and thickness between 10 to 15[mm] (that may also be overengineered) but you will be on the safe side".  That's a great help - thank you!  I would much prefer to go with a Flat bar so that I can conceal it. I'm happy with it being 'over engineered' - just as long as it's safe:-) Once again, thank you for your time. Have a good day.

Comment: @MrsJLO If I didn't misunderstand your wish - use a easy to hide flat bar for the support frame, that is to be welded to the 100x100x4 legs; the suggested 10mm - 15mm thick bar will definitely work, but the width should be wide enough to accommodate the welds on both sides of the leg. It can be done with a flare bevel weld that requires less width. You should check with your welder before order the flat bar.

Comment: @r13 this is exactly what I'm trying to figure out at the moment - the thought crossed my mind as the legs would only actually be touching the ends of the cross section that's in the middle of the frame. I've just googled what a 'flare bevel weld' is, so I do get what you mean. Thank you. Sorry to be so long-winded - I don't know how to add a picture to this comment to better explain!

Comment: @MrsJLO The connection is probably the most important part of your project, it must be strong and stable to hold the legs firmly in place. As suggested, if you are not familiar with welding, you shall engage the person, who is to perform the task, in the planning stage, so not to waste any of the materials.

Comment: @r13 Agreed. I think I've taken this as far as I can. I've taken onboard everyone's comments on this platform, which have been very helpful and much appreciated.  I've amended my drawing accordingly and will speak to the fabricators to ensure all goes to plan. Thank you.  Going to call it a night now.

Comment: @MrsJLO You are welcome. Good luck, and enjoy your new table (through own design).

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable possible concern is flatness of the metal top for the granite to sit on . Welds must be ground smooth at the top of the structure and should be as flat as possible as, no doubt ,the granite is flat. The traditional way to do this is to have the steel firmly held to a "strong back" ( welding table ) during welding. I have a 915 mm X 1730 kitchen island granite that sits on conventional wood frame ,apparently the wood frame was slightly accommodating as the top always sat solid. Your stainless is much stronger and not very accommodating. Granite does well in a garden , I have granite on a carbon steel frame as a planting bench; However, It is a few irregular pieces of granite that were free. Because of limited size ,flatness is no problem.

Comment: Good point @blacksmith37 - I will emphasis the flatness requirement to the fabricators. Getting a bit nervous now - a "back of the envelope" idea is turning into a lot of precision engineering!

Comment: Re: flatness: comment 1: it doesn't need to be ground flat everywhere, just at the high points where there is contact. comment 2: steel frames often can flex slightly to take up slight non-flatnesses. comment 3: a layer can be added between, e.g. rubber sheet. Helps spread out the load too!

Answer (score 0):

Without checking into details or performing calculations, I will go for the flat bar as the first choice, the next choice will be a rectangular box shape with the wider face laying flat.

The reason is that the rigid granite tabletop can span itself to a certain length without relying on the top support frame to carry the load to the support legs, thus the rigidity of the frame member is immaterial, but the thickness of the bar, or the wall thickness of the box shape, shall be sized to resist the potential punching shear from the leg, and to satisfy the requirement of making a sound weld joint.

On your design, you shall make sure the lateral stability is achieved by attaching diagonal bracings to the legs, or rigid brackets that restrict lateral movement, especially in the transverse direction (onto the page).